# Play Framework:@6ddhe2a72 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/tasks]

Tags: playframework-2.1

I have followed the PlayFramework 2.1's [tutorial](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaTodoList) and when I was running the application ,the index page shows normally,but when I click the Button "Create" to create the task,it didn't work,and the console shown that @6ddhe2a72 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/tasks].
I'm puzzled now.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You should run playframework in development mode to see the full error. We cannot help you without that.

Instead of `play start`, simply launch `play run` (read [this page](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/PlayConsole) for more details)

You could also see the stacktrace in the file `log/application.log`.

Comment: Thanks! My application.log says as below:

Comment: ! @6ddhkdl69 - Internal server error, for (GET) [/] ->
play.api.db.evolutions.InvalidDatabaseRevision: Database 'default' needs evolution![An SQL script need to be run on your database.]
 at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin$$anonfun$onStart$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply$mcV$sp(Evolutions.scala:457) ~[play-jdbc_2.10.jar:2.1.0]
 at play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin.withLock

Comment: Your database need an evolution (= an update), the sql file was already generated by play. Run it manually in your sql database, or simpler, launch play in development mode (play run), and follow the instructions.

Comment: Thank you for your help!It's my own fault, I'm too carefuless.And now the problem has been solved.Thanks very much.@Julien Lafont